# "height not divisible by 2" with "min"

Tags: ffmpeg, scaling, x264, libx264

Using this command:

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i q.jpg -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf 'scale=-2:min(1080\,ih)' z.mp4
```

I get this message:

```sh
[libx264 @ 00000000004d0ec0] height not divisible by 2 (954x953)
```

I can avoid the error like this:

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i q.jpg -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=-2:1080 z.mp4
```

However this is not ideal because it is upscaling the image. How can I scale the
image only if the height is greater than 1080, while keeping the pixel format as
I have it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```sh
-vf 'scale=-2:min(1080\,trunc(ih/2)*2)'
```

http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/309

Or:

```sh
-vf 'scale=-2:min(1080\,bitand(ih\,-2))'
```

- http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360348/-/4360378

Or:

```sh
-vf 'scale=-2:min(1080\,ih-mod(ih\,2))'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. For example: ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2  -i fft_%05d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p fft_.mp4 -vf 'scale=-2:min(1080\,trunc(ih/2)*2)' still gives "width not divisible by 2 (2265x2209)".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
'scale=-2:min(1080\,ih)'
```

use

```
'scale=-2:min(1080\,if(mod(ih\,2)\,ih-1\,ih))'
```

It will check if `ih` is divisible by `2`, and if not, it will decrease it by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the exact answer, but my google search led here.
I simply looked at the frame size (in my case I am downsampling) took the size: 1796x1080 and divided 1796 in 2 (898) and used that in the size line:

```
-vf scale=898:-1
```

Which did end up with this size: 898x540